# 1px space on fixed toolbar - jQuery Mobile using Cordova on Microsoft Surface

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, pixelsense

I'm building an Application using jQuery Mobile and using it with Cordova on a Windows Surface.

I have a fixed persistent footer that's outside of my page content.

When viewing it on the screen, the footer has 1px space at the bottom of the screen and another 1px space at the right hand side of the toolbar.

I've tried setting .ui-page, body, and html elements to 100% with no luck.

When scrolling the Lorem Ipsum text you can see in the screenshot you can see the text slide through the white line area.

Note: it's hard to see the white line at the very bottom of the image, under the app on the left pane.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by process of elimination I was able to find the culprit.

I was including Bootstrap 3 in my project and it contains the following CSS declaration that was messing everything up on the surface inside of Cordova.

```
@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;
}
```